# Good practice to build snapshots for your iOS apps?

Tags: ios, app-store

This question is targeted for people who are involved in the iOS apps development. Not sure if suitable to ask such questions here. (correct me if wrong )

Once built one iOS app and uploaded to iTuneConnect, need 5 snapshots for iPhone/iPad to tell users how this app looks like or how it will run. Everyone can see them from the app store before purchase or download it.

My question is to look for good practice to build such snapshots. My previous approach is to snapshot screen directly and just do a few edition to guilde users. That is not enough. And that is not cool.

Any better or cooler approach to do this ? Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-design-tutorials/app-store_screenshot-design_iphone-desig/

It contains tips on how to create good screenshots and gives examples of good and bad screenshot design.